# MinGW cannot compile hello world

Tags: windows, gcc, mingw

I just installed MSYS and MinGW using the default GUI installer, checking all checkboxes. Then I made a simple hello world program and tried to compile it on the MSYS command line. This is what happens:

```
$ gcc test.c
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
   cannot find -lshell32
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
   cannot find -luser32
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
   cannot find -lkernel32
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

With a verbose flag:

```
$ gcc -v test.c
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.6.2/configure --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --enable-shared --enable-libgomp --disable-win32-registry --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --build=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.6.2 (GCC) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=i386' '-march=i386'
 c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/cc1.exe -quiet -v -iprefix c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/ test.c -quiet -dumpbase test.c -mtune=i386 -march=i386 -auxbase test -version -o C:\DOCUME~1\Owner\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccz34YZu.s
GNU C (GCC) version 4.6.2 (mingw32)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.6.2, GMP version 5.0.1, MPFR version 2.4.1, MPC version 0.8.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=82 --param ggc-min-heapsize=98237
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../include
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include-fixed
End of search list.
GNU C (GCC) version 4.6.2 (mingw32)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.6.2, GMP version 5.0.1, MPFR version 2.4.1, MPC version 0.8.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=82 --param ggc-min-heapsize=98237
Compiler executable checksum: c20aed7c018482d7b62efcd5dcab2a9d
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=i386' '-march=i386'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/as.exe -o C:\DOCUME~1\Owner\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccgcJLdQ.o C:\DOCUME~1\Owner\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccz34YZu.s
COMPILER_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/;c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/lib/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../;/mingw/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=i386' '-march=i386'
 c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/collect2.exe -Bdynamic c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../crt2.o c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/crtbegin.o -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2 -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/lib -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../.. -L/mingw/lib C:\DOCUME~1\Owner\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccgcJLdQ.o -lmingw32 -lgcc_eh -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmingw32 -lgcc_eh -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/crtend.o
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lshell32
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -luser32
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lkernel32
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What did I do wrong? Do I need Microsoft development libraries, and if I do, where can I get them?

Comment: try `gcc -v test.c` to get a bit more information on your specific error (it's the _verbose_ switch)

Comment: There you go. I added the output of gcc -v.

Comment: Actually the `-Wl,--verbose` option to gcc would probably be more informative - that tells the linker to indicate where it's looking for libraries.  The Win SDK libraries in my mingw32 4.6.1 install are in c:\mingw32\lib, but that MinGW is a TDM distribution.  I haven't messed with the official MinGW installer in quite a long time - I found it too complicated.

Comment: I see that `/mingw/lib/` is in the `LIBRARY_PATH` - what files are in there?  `libkernel32.a` and friends should be in there.

Comment: Why the downvote? I've been struggling over this for days and Google is extremely unhelpful. I'll look into /mingw/lib and see what's there.

Comment: @Eric: unless you really want to understand what's gone wrong with your installation (which I completely understand - I'm pretty sure I'd dog my way through the problem), you might want to consider just installing a TDM or nuwen distribution of MinGW. Their installation is much more straightforward than the official MinGW distribution (nuwen's installation is simply unpacking an archive).

Comment: OK I think I'll get nuwen. It's interesting though. Why are the official MinGW packages so difficult to install correctly even though the installer just has a few options? Cygwin was a breeze compared to this.

Comment: I not entirely sure why the official distribution is like that. They seem to want the project to stay a confederation of separate but related projects (the compiler, the runtime, the Windows SDK, MSYS, etc.) that gets assembled at installation time instead of rolling everything into a single project.  I'm sure there are good reasons for that, but as far as I'm concerned grabbing a single archive and unpacking it is what lazy-me likes.

Comment: Is there in your path environment variable a part like : `C:\mingw;C:\mingw\bin` ? And in your `C:\mingw\lib` a `libkernel32.a` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking if all the environmental variables were properly set when you were installing mingw and MSYS.

Answer (score 0):

there is a mistake in environment variable try path and add browse for mingw/bin

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).